# Unexpected $end , expecting kEND

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

My task is to make a more efficient binary search code using Ruby. I followed the logic from this link:
http://www.cprogramming.com/discussionarticles/sorting_and_searching.html

My code is as follows:

```
def bsearch(a, k)

  lower = 0
  upper = a.length-1

  while a[upper].to_f> k.to_f and a[lower].to_f< k.to_f
    low_diff = k.to_f -a[lower].to_f
    range_diff = a[upper].to_f-a[lower].to_f
    count_diff = upper-lower
    range = low_diff/range_diff * count_diff  + lower

    if k==a[lower]
      return lower

    if k.to_f > a[range].to_f
      lower = range+1
    else if k.to_f <  a[range].to_f
      upper =range
    else    
      lower = range
    end

  end
end
```

I double check, but I do not know why I keep experiencing the followin error:

```
unexpected $end , expecting kEND
```

Answer (score 7):

You lost an `end` in one of the `if` statement. And instead of `else if`, the keyword in Ruby is `elsif`

```
if k==a[lower]
    return lower
end                             #lost this end
if k.to_f > a[range].to_f
    lower = range+1
elsif k.to_f <  a[range].to_f   #use elsif
    upper =range
else    
    lower = range
end
```

Comment: Hi Yu Hao, my results yield nill when its suppose to return a location in the array, please help

Comment: @user2445971 That's a different question, as I only checked the compilation error when I posted the answer. It's better to ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write **else if** in ruby you should write **elsif**

```
  def bsearch(a, k)

  lower = 0
  upper = a.length-1

  while a[upper].to_f> k.to_f && a[lower].to_f< k.to_f
    low_diff = k.to_f -a[lower].to_f
    range_diff = a[upper].to_f-a[lower].to_f
    count_diff = upper-lower
    range = low_diff/range_diff * count_diff  + lower
    if k==a[lower]
      return lower
    end
    if k.to_f > a[range].to_f
      lower = range+1
    elsif k.to_f <  a[range].to_f
      upper =range
    else    
      lower = range
    end 
  end
end
```